# Scraping website bullet points

Tags: android, tags, scrape

Extremely new to coding(yesterday)

I have been given the task of creating a Android app for a friend to pull the data from his website and insert it into a quick app rather than him and his colleagues having to open a browser every time they would like to view it.

For reasons, I cannot share the website address.
The data on the website is in a bullet point list.

I have been reading some tutorials and watching some videos, I can pull the website up using WebView and I have now started reading up on JSoup. I have copied a few lines of code from some tutorials and I can now pull the website up in raw/html/just plain text but I could like to remove the unnecessary data and just have the text next to the bullet points.

Here is my code from MainActivity.java

As previously mentioned, I am extremely new to this with no background experience.

What I would like to know is if I can scrape the text between two tags on the page source for example between "div class="scheduler" SCRAPE THE TEXT HERE "ul id="myUL"

That would have all of the information I need in the above tags.

Thank you.

```html
package spcentral.jsouptut;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
        import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
        import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
        import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

        import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button getBtn;
    private TextView result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        getBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getBtn);
        getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getWebsite();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getWebsite() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("linkremoved").get();
                    String text = doc.text();
                    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

                                        builder.append(text).append("n");

                    for (Element link : links) {
                        builder.append("n").append("Link : ").append(link.attr("href"))
                                .append("n").append("Text : ").append(link.text());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("n");
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        result.setText(builder.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: You can use regular expressions for that I guess.

Comment: Could you please run through it with me please? I'm still learning what and where to input code. Thank you.

Comment: Okay. But a add a sample html from which you want to extract data from.

Comment: <div class="scheduler">

        <h4>Today's Schedule</h4>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Type here to filter the events:" title="Type in a name" class="placeholder">
        <br>

        <br><ul id="myUL">
        HERE IS THE DATA I WANT I WANT TO SCRAPE</ul>
          <br>
               </div>

Comment: Sorry that didn't come out as I would like to. That is some of the html on his website. I need to scrape the data between the tags <myUL> and </ul>

Comment: <ul.*id="myUL">.*.</ul> try this regular expression.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Where should I insert this?